# Delphi XE7 iOs Developing

Tags: ios, delphi, delphi-xe7

I'm trying to set up the environment for installing an iOS App developed by Delphi XE7. The thing is my Mac OS X is the version 10.6.8 and the higgest Xcode I can install is the 3.2. Is it possible to work with such scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Installation_Notes_for_XE7#Requirements_for_Developing_iOS_Applications) answers your question

> **Requirements for Developing iOS Applications**
>
> - PC running Windows connected to an Intel-based Mac, or a Mac running Windows in a VM, with 2 GB RAM or more.
> - The Mac ***must run OS X 10.9 or 10.8, with the latest version of Xcode that supports iOS 7 or iOS 8***.
> - An Apple Developer account is required to deploy iOS apps to physical devices.
> - Platform Assistant server (paserver) installed on the Mac:

emphasis mine.

Comment: Thanks, i knew it already. I just wanted to avoid to buy a new Mac for developing with delphi xe7. I installed vmware fusion and virtualize a Mac os 10.8 with xcode and Paserver and everything is working perfectly.